# Binding custom IPrincipal and IIdentity with Ninject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject

I am trying to bind the IIdentity from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity to a custom IPrincipal but from what I can gather, IIdentity is null before user is authenticated.

Sample code:

```
public interface ICustomPrincipal
{
    int UserID { get; set; }
}

public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
{
    private readonly IIdentity _identity;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public CustomPrincipal(IIdentity identity, IUserRepository repository)
    {
        _identity = identity;
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

And then

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(".axd"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.User as CustomPrincipal;
    }
}
```

I can bind IUserRepository no problem but I do not know how to properly bind IIdentity.

I have tried to bind the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity in CreateKernel() on Application_Start, but the problem is, the IIdentity is null.

I have also tried using GlobalFilters and Ninject.BindFilter method to set the CustomPrincipal but the problem revolves back to IIdentity being null.

I do not want to call the constructor of CustomPrincipal because IUserRepository also involves constructor injection.

I'm unsure of whether I am not binding correctly, or my implementation method is not right, any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

What I am trying to achieve in the end is to pass ICustomPrincipal down to the DB level to record the UserID on transactions.

Thanks

Comment: forms based authentication ? You only access the Identity info once authenticated is true ?

Comment: Yes its form based. I tried accessing it on application start but with little success

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample showing bootstrap AFTER and BEFORE authentication

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        //BundleMobileConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    private bool _isBootStrapped;
    private bool _isBootStrappedAuthenticated;

    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
        // handlers managed by ASP.Net during Forms authentication
        BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequestHandler);
        PostAuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(PostAuthHandler);
        EndRequest += new EventHandler(EndRequestHandler);
    }

    public void EndRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void BeginRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BootStrapUnauthentiated();
    }

    public void PostAuthHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isBootStrappedAuthenticated)
        {
            return; // nuff done...
        }
        BootStrapAuthenticated();
        BootStrapUnauthentiated();
    }

    private void BootStrapAuthenticated()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            BootStrapHttp(Context);
            BootStrapper.RegisterInfrastureAdapters();

            _isBootStrapped = true;
            _isBootStrappedAuthenticated = true;
        }
    }

    private void BootStrapUnauthentiated()
    {
        if (!_isBootStrapped)
        { // minimal bootstrap for launch but user not yet known, eg logon screen

            BootStrapHttp(Context);
            BootStrapper.RegisterInfrastureAdapters();
           _isBootStrapped = true; // just a connection, if no persisted cookie, the may not be authenticated yet
        }
    }
}
```